# Rails dropdown state change in show view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I have this in my form for state change (using simple_form gem).

```
<%= f.input :state, collection: [ ['bids', 'Bid'], ['in_progress', 'In Progress'], ['complete', 'Complete'] ], as: :radio_buttons, label_method: :last, value_method: :first %>
```

What I'd like to do as well is allow user to change this state in the show view after an 'job' is created with a simple drop-down: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

So drop-down shows current state and if user clicks and selects a different state, the model is automatically updated. I would like to do this without a submit button - automatic submit - javascript, I suppose?

Do I need to make changes to my controller for (edit / update)? I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to add a Javascript hook to the change event of that dropdown, grab the currently selected value, and do an AJAX POST to your controller. It's no different than any other `update` functionality you might implement in Rails.